# Is it possible to change cell ref inside a formula based on activeRange?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

## I want to Change cell number inside formula based on where it is.

The user of the sheet with my script can click a menu item to add a layout that contains a preset of formulas. But when I run my script the cells where my formula is does not change the cell ref based on where the user add the layout.

I'm also looking for a way to have it preset to a layout with 5 rows, 10 rows, 15 rows that will have calculation formulas.

So when the user have cell A1 activated and goes in the menu, he/she can choose if they want 5, 10, 15 rows to add items.

This is going to be a script inside the sheet for calculating food cost not only how much it cost to make a recipe but also how much it needs to be priced at to not loose money.

I have not found any answer online or through Youtube to point me in the right direction. Have looked for answers on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/  and still can't understand how to make it the way I want it to be.

```
\\\ function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Kalkyle')
      .addItem('Sett inn layout', 'layout')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Ny Kalkyle', 'nyKalkyle')
      .addToUi();
}    

function nyKalkyle() {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
 var numFormat = sheet.setNumberFormat("0.00 KR");
 var range = "Navn:";
 var range1 = "Salgspris:";
 var range2 = "Varenummer";
 var range3 = "Varenavn";
 var range4 = "Pris pr kg";
 var range5 = "Pris pr gr";
 var range6 = "Svinn %";
 var range7 = "Vår mengde"; 
 var range8 = "Råvarekostnad";
 var range9 = "Varekost";
 var range10 = "";

 // OppskriftNavn
 sheet.setValue(range); 

 // SalgsPris
 sheet.offset(0, 3).setValue(range1); 

  // Råvarekostnad
  sheet.offset(1, 3).setValue(range8); 

  // Formel Råvarekostand
  sheet.offset(1, 4).setFormula('=sum(G9:G15)').setNumberFormat("#,## kr");
```

The range (G9:G15) needs to change based on where the layout is passed in. It gets passed in by the user in the active cell when he/she clicks "Ny kalkyle

```
  // Varekost
  sheet.offset(0, 5).setValue(range9);

  // Formel Varekost
  sheet.offset(0, 6).setFormula('=E4/E3'); 

  // Varenummer
  sheet.offset(4, 0).setValue(range2).setBackground("lightgray"); 

  // Formel Finn varenummer
  sheet.offset(6, 0).setFormula('=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(UNIQUE(Query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PagM-gaCoKXV012t-AzaTsk5o3GUd0YGXeXOSECSWVo/edit#gid=0";"A2:C");"Select Col1 where Col2=\'"&B9&"\'"))))');
```

The range ("B9") needs to change based on where the layout is passed in. It gets passed in by the user in the active cell when he/she clicks "Ny kalkyle"

```
  // Varenavn
  sheet.offset(4, 1).setValue(range3).setBackground("lightgray"); 

  // Pris pr kg
 sheet.offset(4, 2).setValue(range4).setBackground("lightgray");
```

The range ("B9") needs to change based on where the layout is passed in. It gets passed in by the user in the active cell when he/she clicks "Ny kalkyle"

```
  // Formel Finn KG pris  
  sheet.offset(6, 2).setFormula('=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(UNIQUE(Query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PagM-gaCoKXV012t-AzaTsk5o3GUd0YGXeXOSECSWVo/edit#gid=0";"A2:E");"Select Col3 where Col2=\'"&B9&"\'"))))').setNumberFormat("#,## kr");

  // Pris pr gr
  sheet.offset(4, 3).setValue(range5).setBackground("lightgray"); 

  // Formel Pris pr gr
  sheet.offset(6, 3).setFormula('=C9/1000'); 

 // Svinn %
 sheet.offset(4, 4).setValue(range6).setBackground("lightgray");  

 // Formel svinn
 sheet.offset(6, 4).setNumberFormat("#,###%");

 // Vår mengde
 sheet.offset(4, 5).setValue(range7).setBackground("lightgray");  

 // Råvarekostnad
 sheet.offset(4, 6).setValue(range8).setBackground("lightgray");
```

The range inside the setFormula needs to change based on where the layout is passed in. It gets passed in by the user in the active cell when he/she clicks "Ny kalkyle"

```
  // Formel Råvarekostnad
 sheet.offset(6, 6).setFormula('=ArrayFormula(IF(C9;D9*F9+(E9/1*D9*F9);""))').numFormat;

}
```

I want every cell ref to change when a user deside to put in the layout.

If he/she have cell A1 activated, the cell ref needs to ref the correct cells inside the formulas.

The same if he/she have cell A25 activated.

But based on my script it does not change, and that makes it so the calculation does not add up correct and then the user have to change the cell ref everythime the layout is passed in, and that makes it so my script is pointless.

**EDIT**

After the help of you in this community and a lot of search on google, I have ended up with a result that works the way I have seen for myself. Now it remains to find a way to add a dropdown list with a range just as data validation

Here is the script I ended up with https://pastebin.com/TBw86PtK

Comment: Use R1C1 referencing style instead of A1 notation.

Comment: I have read something about R1C1 referencing style when I looked for a clue on how to get my script to act the way I want it to. But I can't understand how that will help with the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use getActiveRange to get the active cell and update all your formulas with string substitution, but this is a poor solution which will be difficult to manage.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
var active_row = sheet.getRow();
var active_column = sheet.getColumn();
/* 
  various math here to calculate correct row/column values,
  and convert them into A1 notation inside strings

  NOT RECOMMENDED!
*/
```

You are much better off to use the relative form of R1C1 notation, which uses square braces. EG: R[1]C[1].  When you use a square brace around the numbers in R1C1, it indicates the number of rows or columns *relative* to the current cell.  If you specify R[1]C[1] in Cell A1, you are referencing cell B2 (Row + 1, Column + 1),  or one row below and one column to the right of the active cell.   Similarly, you can use 0 or negative numbers in the square braces . 0 refers to the current Row or Column, and negative will move "up" and "left" for rows and columns.

- R[0]C[2] in cell A1 will yield the value in cell C1. (row + 0, column +2)
- R[-2]C[-1] in cell B3 will yield the value in cell A1. (row -2, column -1)

So, by using relative R1C1 notation, you can ensure all your formulas will reference cells relative to where they are inserted in the sheet.

After updating your formulas to R1C1 notation, you will need to use the `SetFormulaR1C1` function instead of `SetFormula`

So, assuming the formulas you wrote in your existing code are relative to A1, it would look something like this:

```
sheet.offset(1, 4).setFormulaR1C1('=sum(R[8]C[3]:R[14]C[3])').setNumberFormat("#,## kr");
```

Comment: This did solve a major part on my script! Thank you for that!

Comment: I have an idea, let say you write the formula to one cell with the appropriate cell references.  Get the range of that cell and then range.copyTo(..) the other cells you want the formula in.  This acts like cut and paste and automatically adjust the cell references in the copies.